# 「思っているようです。」or 「思っている。」 for describing another person's opinion

Tags: verbs

As explained in the thread [Difference between そうです、 ようです and らしいです.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/16312/difference-between-%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99-%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99-and-%E3%82%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99), when describing what you think are the thoughts of another person, might 「思っているようです。」 be more appropriate than 「思っている。」?

(1) <strike>今{いま}の景気{けいき}では、Bobさんによれば、株価{かぶか}が高{たか}いと思っている。</strike>
(2) <strike>今の景気では、Bobさんによれば、株価が高いと思っているようです。</strike>

I think that #2 sounds better.

Other than speaking for myself, or a group that I represent, is not 「思っているようです」 the better option? After all, you are only capable of stating what you think the other person appears to be thinking.

Comment: Japanese-speaker here.  TBH, both sentences sound strange because of the combination of 「Bobさんによれば」 and 「思っている」. 　You are, in effect, saying "According to Bob, he thinks that ~~~."　Is it OK to say that in English?  Even if it were, it would not be in Japanese.  I can see that you are trying to ask a good question, though.

Comment: I am not so good at ex. sentences.. btw: If I just say "高いと思っているようです。"、then does this create an implied subject (anyone, but not me). "高いと思う" creates an implied subject (me)?

Comment: ２つの例文の、「株価が高いと思っている」の主語はBobさんなんですか？

Comment: One might hear  "According to Bob, he thinks that ~~~." in spoken English but it would be broken, just it would be in Japanese.  The structure　「Bobさんの話では〜そうです。」might be what you are looking for?

Comment: @Choko I sensed that perhaps "と思っている。" had the implied subject which is "I", and "と思っているようです。" has the implied subject which is "anyone other than me". To me, it seems that "myself" is the only possible subject for 「株価が高いと思っている。」

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say

> ボブさんは、物価が高いと思っている。(casual form)
>   ボブさんは、物価が高いと思っています。(polite form)
>   (not *ボブさんは、物価が高いと思う。/ *ボブさんは、物価が高いと思います。)

to say "Bob thinks that prices are high",

> ボブさんは、物価が高いと思っているようだ。(casual form)
>   ボブさんは、物価が高いと思っているようです。(polite form)

to say "It seems that Bob thinks prices are high", and

> ボブさんによれば、物価が高いそうだ。(casual form)
>   ボブさんによれば、物価が高いそうです。(polite form)

to say "According to Bob, prices are high" (or "Bob says that prices are high.")

---

If I heard/read

> ボブさんによれば、物価が高いと思っているようだ。(casual form)
>   ボブさんによれば、物価が高いと思っているようです。(polite form)

I would feel like asking "誰が(物価が高いと思っているの)？(Who thinks that prices are high?)"

I would rather expect something like

> ボブさんによれば、XXさんは物価が高いと思っているようだ。(casual form)
>   ボブさんによれば、XXさんは物価が高いと思っているようです。(polite form)

which means "According to Bob, (it seems that) XX thinks that prices are high", or

> ボブさんによれば、XXさんは物価が高いと思っているそうだ。(casual form)
>   ボブさんによれば、XXさんは物価が高いと思っているそうです。(polite form)

which means "According to Bob, (I hear that) XX thinks that prices are high." (Bob told me that XX thinks that prices are high.)

---

By the way, if I just heard

> 物価が高いと思う。
>   物価が高いと思います。
>   物価が高いと思っている。
>   物価が高いと思っています。

then I would think that the subject is "I", the speaker.

Comment: Thanks for broadening the answer to pretty much all the questions I really did have.

Answer (score 2):

I think #2 is a little more natural especially in everyday conversation. However, #1 is still often found in articles or such.

off-topic: 
If you want to use ～によれば, it's 「…によれば今の…では株価が高い。」, 「・・・株価が高いそうだ」 or 「・・・株価が高いとのこと(だ)」

Bobさんによれば株価が高いと思っている(ようだ) means "Bob said he/she (not Bob himself) thinks stock price is high for the current economy".