# The differences between そうです ・ ようです

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I'm recently revising my Japanese for the upcoming JLPT this July (I'm taking N4), and I came up with difficulties in using these 2 items.

For example:

> 気分が良くなりました。やっとねつが  (下がりました...)。

(I have to choose そうです ・ ようです to fill in the blank)

Can there be a simple way to distinguish between them?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: Clearly, here the two sentences are fine. It's just that そう reports 伝聞 whereas よう describe a 状態. Thus, if *you* are talking (気分が良くなりました。could be an hint) then you describe your situation (directly) thus you would use よう.

Comment: This thread might be some help... http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16312

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter what your choice be, you can append ようです or そうです, the sentence will be grammatically perfect. What is important here is the context.

The sentence

> 気分が良くなりました。

indicates that the speaker talks about himself, otherwise, the statement should be less direct. Thus the fact that the fever cooled is first-hand information from the speaker, he describes his state (that is what ようです is for: describing a state) whereas そうです when appended to a 終止形 indicates rumor (it seems that, it is said that, ...) not to be mixed up with the そうです that clip itself on the 連用形 and express also a state (in the same way as ようです).

To sum up, here the speaker describes a first-hand fact, thus he can't use そうです here, ようです is the correct answer.

EDIT: As pointed out by chocolate, よう・そう would rather connect to さがった rather than さがりました.

Comment: そのままくっつけて「さがりました＋ようです」にせず、「 **さがった** ＋ようです」に形を変えることも、一言、付け加えて差し上げれば、なおのことよろしいかと... ＾＾