# What's the difference between そうな/に (sou na/ni) and ような/に (you na/ni)?

Tags: grammar

I'm a beginner in Japanese.

I know ように can mean "as", "so", "like",
and よう can mean "look like".
And I know that そう can mean  "seem like", "that way", "or such", but there are too many possible combinations similar to よう.

In another [post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/16312/difference-between-%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99-%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99-and-%E3%82%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99) the difference was explained for  そうだ　and ようだ.
Here I'm asking that can you explain what そう means for the other scenarios like そうに/な (compared to よう).

For example in the following sentence:

> 優{やさ}しそうなご両親{りようしん}でしたね
>   "They looked like very kind parents."

What is the difference from よう in this example or other possible combinations?

Comment: this post asks for other scenarios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

～そうな is generally used in a context of "seems like" based on appearances.

～ような is generally used when you're talking about a resemblance to something. In other words, ～ような is more directly related to the English concept of a simile, *A like a B.*

For example:

```
彼女は優しそうな人です。
```

"She seems like a nice person."

```
彼女はメイドのような人です。
```

"She looks like a maid."

```
あのケーキは美味しそうです。
```

"That cake looks delicious."

```
あのケーキは雲のようにふわふわです。
```

"That cake is fluffy like a cloud."

As you can see, the difference is subtle, but important.

In both cases, the difference of na/ni comes down to adjectival vs adverbial forms.

そうに～ Would be something along the lines of "seemingly."

Whereas ように～ Still translates as "...like a..." in English, as English has no real equivalent adverbial form.

You can think of it like this: when it's ～な it's always going to expect a noun to modify. When it's ～に it's going to expect a verb to modify:

```
鳥のようなすがた
```

"looks like/shaped like a bird"

```
鳥のように飛んだ
```

"flew like a bird"

```
転びそうな建物
```

"A building that looks like it'd fall over"

```
建物は転びそうにゆらゆらした
```

"The building swayed as though it'd fall over"

Comment: So I guess it is the same as "sou/you da"

Comment: Yes. な is often used in place of だ to turn a phrase in copula form (being) into an adjectival form. It's the reason why な adjectives are ended with だ when you want to say "something is..." 

EX: 「静かな部屋。」 "A quiet room" vs. 「部屋は静かだ。」 "The room is quiet."

Comment: Thanks, I think "as though" was a good example.